# Forward fill seasonal data in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have hourly observations of several variables that exhibit daily seasonality. I want to fill any missing value with the corresponding variable's value 24 hours prior.

Ideally my function would fill the missing values from oldest to newest. Thus if there are 25 consecutive missing values, the 25th missing value is filled with the same value as the first missing value. Using Series.map() fails in this case.

```py
                         value  desired_output
hour                                          
2019-08-17 00:00:00  58.712986       58.712986
2019-08-17 01:00:00  28.904234       28.904234
2019-08-17 02:00:00  14.275149       14.275149
2019-08-17 03:00:00  58.777087       58.777087
2019-08-17 04:00:00  95.964955       95.964955
2019-08-17 05:00:00  64.971372       64.971372
2019-08-17 06:00:00  95.759469       95.759469
2019-08-17 07:00:00  98.675457       98.675457
2019-08-17 08:00:00  77.510319       77.510319
2019-08-17 09:00:00  56.492446       56.492446
2019-08-17 10:00:00  90.968924       90.968924
2019-08-17 11:00:00  66.647501       66.647501
2019-08-17 12:00:00   7.756725        7.756725
2019-08-17 13:00:00  49.328135       49.328135
2019-08-17 14:00:00  28.634033       28.634033
2019-08-17 15:00:00  65.157161       65.157161
2019-08-17 16:00:00  93.127539       93.127539
2019-08-17 17:00:00  98.806335       98.806335
2019-08-17 18:00:00  94.789761       94.789761
2019-08-17 19:00:00  63.518037       63.518037
2019-08-17 20:00:00  89.524433       89.524433
2019-08-17 21:00:00  48.076081       48.076081
2019-08-17 22:00:00   5.027928        5.027928
2019-08-17 23:00:00   0.417763        0.417763
2019-08-18 00:00:00  29.933627       29.933627
2019-08-18 01:00:00  61.726948       61.726948
2019-08-18 02:00:00        NaN       14.275149
2019-08-18 03:00:00        NaN       58.777087
2019-08-18 04:00:00        NaN       95.964955
2019-08-18 05:00:00        NaN       64.971372
2019-08-18 06:00:00        NaN       95.759469
2019-08-18 07:00:00        NaN       98.675457
2019-08-18 08:00:00        NaN       77.510319
2019-08-18 09:00:00        NaN       56.492446
2019-08-18 10:00:00        NaN       90.968924
2019-08-18 11:00:00        NaN       66.647501
2019-08-18 12:00:00        NaN        7.756725
2019-08-18 13:00:00        NaN       49.328135
2019-08-18 14:00:00        NaN       28.634033
2019-08-18 15:00:00        NaN       65.157161
2019-08-18 16:00:00        NaN       93.127539
2019-08-18 17:00:00        NaN       98.806335
2019-08-18 18:00:00        NaN       94.789761
2019-08-18 19:00:00        NaN       63.518037
2019-08-18 20:00:00        NaN       89.524433
2019-08-18 21:00:00        NaN       48.076081
2019-08-18 22:00:00        NaN        5.027928
2019-08-18 23:00:00        NaN        0.417763
2019-08-19 00:00:00        NaN       29.933627
2019-08-19 01:00:00        NaN       61.726948
2019-08-19 02:00:00        NaN       14.275149
2019-08-19 03:00:00        NaN       58.777087
2019-08-19 04:00:00        NaN       95.964955
2019-08-19 05:00:00        NaN       64.971372
2019-08-19 06:00:00        NaN       95.759469
2019-08-19 07:00:00        NaN       98.675457
2019-08-19 08:00:00        NaN       77.510319
2019-08-19 09:00:00        NaN       56.492446
2019-08-19 10:00:00        NaN       90.968924
2019-08-19 11:00:00        NaN       66.647501
2019-08-19 12:00:00        NaN        7.756725
2019-08-19 13:00:00  61.457913       61.457913
2019-08-19 14:00:00  52.429383       52.429383
2019-08-19 15:00:00  79.016485       79.016485
2019-08-19 16:00:00  77.724758       77.724758
2019-08-19 17:00:00  62.205810       62.205810
2019-08-19 18:00:00  15.841707       15.841707
2019-08-19 19:00:00  72.196028       72.196028
2019-08-19 20:00:00   5.497441        5.497441
2019-08-19 21:00:00  30.737596       30.737596
2019-08-19 22:00:00  65.550690       65.550690
2019-08-19 23:00:00   3.543332        3.543332

import pandas as pd
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta as rel_delta

df['isna'] = df['value'].isna()
df['value'] = df.index.map(lambda t: df.at[t - rel_delta(hours=24), 'value'] if df.at[t,'isna'] and t - rel_delta(hours=24) >= df.index.min() else df.at[t, 'value'])
```

What is the most efficient way to complete this naive forward fill?

Comment: What is your desired output. Especially if there is no value 24hours prior. Can oyu define that?

Comment: @jottbe I added clarification. Thanks!

Comment: can you post your expected output?

Comment: I have posted the desired output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IIUC, just `groupby` time and `ffill()`

```
df['resuts'] = df.groupby(df.hour.dt.time).value.ffill()
```

If `hour` is your index, just do `df.index.time` instead.

Checking:

```
>>> (df['results'] == df['desired_output']).all()
True
```

Comment: `groupby` hour using `dt.time` is very very neat

Comment: Is there a way to make this work for multiple columns sharing an index?

Comment: @Rations yep. Just `df.groupby(df.hour.dt.time).ffill()` to apply that to all columns, or `df.groupby(df.hour.dt.time)[['col1', 'col2', ....]].ffill()` for selected columns

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't this work?

```
df['value'] = df['value'].fillna(df.index.hour)
```

Comment: No, the table I posted is a stylized example. In practice the values would not always correspond to the hour of day.

Answer (score 0):

Separate Date and Time into two columns as strings. Call it `df`.

```
      Date       Time         Value
0   2019-08-17  00:00:00     58.712986  
1   2019-08-17  01:00:00     28.904234  
2   2019-08-17  02:00:00     14.275149  
3   2019-08-17  03:00:00     58.777087   
4   2019-08-17  04:00:00     95.964955
```

Then conducts data reshaping, pivot Time into column headers, forward fillna along each hour.

(df reshaping)

```
Date       00:00:00     01:00:00    02:00:00    03:00:00    04:00:00 
2019-08-17  58.712986   28.904234   14.275149   58.777087   95.964955
2019-08-18  29.933627   61.726948       NaN       NaN        NaN
2019-08-19  NaN          NaN            NaN       NaN        NaN
```

(df ffill)

```
Date        00:00:00    01:00:00    02:00:00    03:00:00    04:00:00 
2019-08-17  58.712986   28.904234   14.275149   58.777087   95.964955
2019-08-18  29.933627   61.726948   14.275149   58.777087   95.964955
2019-08-19  29.933627   61.726948   14.275149   58.777087   95.964955
```

(Code)

```
(df.set_index(['Date','Time')['Value']
   .unstack()
   .ffill()
   .stack()
   .reset_index(name='Value')
```

Answer (score 0):

The idea of using `groupby` in conjunction with `ffill()` is a very robust yet great idea.

In timeseries, however, I encountered situations where you need to fill the `NaN`s using arbitrary seasonality (for example: you might want to do fill the `NaN`s by using the same value a week prior against each hour).

In that case, let's assume the following dataframe with columns `timestamp` and `values` where the `values` contains `NaN`s (may be in sparse or consecutive manner).

Following should work:

```
import pandas as pd

n= 24
df["shifte_values"] = df["values"].shift(periods = n)
df["values"] = df.apply(lambda x: x.values if pd.notnull(x) else x.shifted_values, axis = 1)
```

Sometimes the consecutive missing value region can be long, in that case the above approach will still leave `NaN`s. However, you can put the above snippet in a loop and keep iterating as long as there are no `NaN`s left (there might be some caveats here)!